# How to add an HTML <rel=preload> tag to the Header?

Tags: templates

Since the google speed insights report suggests adding a

< link rel="preload" href="/lity.css" as="style" />

to speed up the loading of the following resources

https://www.myoutlet.lt/wp-content/plugins/gdpr-cookie-compliance/dist/styles/lity.css

on the website https://www.myoutlet.lt

The website is based on the Avada theme.

I am wondering how could I possibly achieve that!

More concretely, I've thrown a glance to the header.php file of both the main and the child theme, but since they are coded in PHP I can't really figure out on my own how to add any HTML to it.

There should be for sure a way to inject HTML into the webpage by means of recurring to some php-function in the header.php file. As a junior SEO I acquired some technical understanding, but I'm very far from being a developer.

The one who will show me the way will earn my eternal gratitude! Thank you very much in advance for any valuable hint.

May the force be with you,
Roman

P.S.: I have to achieve this manually, without any plugins (the website is already quite slow on itself!)

Answer (score 2):

The hook you're looking for is [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

*functions.php*

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'se343581_add_preload_tag', 5);
function se343581_add_preload_tag()
{
    echo '<link rel="preload" href="'. 
         plugins_url('/gdpr-cookie-compliance/dist/styles/lity.css') .
         '" as="style">';
    //
    // -- if added in plugin file --
    // echo '<link rel="preload" href="' . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'some_subdir/file_name.css" as="style">';
}
```

Comment: Let's be a little bit more precise, please. To which file should I add the snippet you posted? functions.php or rather header.php? Will this alone do the job or have I to add anything else elsewhere?

Comment: I've tried to do what you told me in the header.php file, but it did not work out! I need a more descriptive intro.. not all of us are born programmers x)

Comment: You can add this code to `functions.php` or to plugin main file.

Comment: I have to perform this workaround through the functions.php ; so, let's get clear on it: I have added this snippet to the very bottom of the functions.php add_action( 'wp_head', 'se343581_add_preload_tag', 5);
function se343581_add_preload_tag()
{
    echo '<link rel="preload" href="/lity.css" as="style">';
   }

Comment: And it is still not working. Where can I define the path you posted, namely home_url('wp-content/plugins/gdpr-cookie-compliance/dist/styles/lity.css') ... I can HTML/CSS but not PHP

Comment: Thank you for the update! Do I have to copy&paste your revised snippet as it is or do I have to tweak anything within it? It is still not working and the syntax of ___ echo '<link rel="preload" href="'. 
         plugins_url('/gdpr-cookie-compliance/dist/styles/lity.css') . ___ looks quite odd to me.

Comment: You do not have to change anything. ( [plugins_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) )

Comment: Ok, I've done this very simple copy&paste action, but google speed insights is telling me that this resource is not preloading. Such a pity! I thought it was a quite easy fix, but, apparently, it is not